# What are the system requirements of ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse

Please let me know the recommend requirement to run the eclipse and Android emulator simantaniously?

I've a laptop powered by Intel i3 processor 1.7 GHz clock speed, 4 GB RAM and windows 10, Bitdefender antivirus installed but I'm not able to work on these tools smoothly. But on desktop powered by 2.8GHz dual core 3GB ram it works smoothly.

The Android emulator is only showing Android logo at very slowly and it doesn't starts up for about 10 minutes on idle.

Please list down all the recommended requirement which are required to run eclipse and Android emulator simantaniously and smoothly on laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest switching to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html). [Support for ADT has ended](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html). Moreover, make sure that you have updated Android SDK. There were improvements in emulators and system images in the last years, which made them faster. You can also switch to Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) because then you can use hardware acceleration for emulators. I'm not sure if it's working on MS Windows. If this won't help, you can try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: Can Android studio will work smoothly in my system? If no then please let me know the recommended system requirements to run it smoothly.

Comment: You can find system requirements here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html. I think it should work fine on your computer. At least you can check it.

Comment: OK I will check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Intel HAXM https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager and x86 image in AVD to improve the performance?

In any case, imho to run smootly AVD on a notebook you should have an i7 ULV 2c/4t (i7 4500U or better) and 8gb of RAM.

Comment: OK I'll try Intel HAXM.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For development purpose do not use eclipse now, use Android Studio because Google has stopped there support to eclipse. In android studio you can use Genymotion it is faster then eclipse's android emulator.

And about your question the ADT emulator is very slow you have to wait a log time to its get started.Your laptop's configuration is enough. you can use Bluestack http://www.bluestacks.com/  or simply connect your android device via usb and run it on directoly using ADB.

Comment: I've heard about Android studio that it is very heavy software that works only on heavy systems.

Comment: Intel i3 processor 1.7 GHz clock speed, 4 GB RAM is sufficient, I have been working for 2 years on android studio with same hardware that you have. only deference is, I am using it on Linux OS.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion